# Great websites for beginner reading

Tags: discussion, resources

I am wanting to focus on reading. But I'm finding it hard to find websites for kids to go on, or websites with stories for kids to read.

I came across this site which has fairy tales, but I'd like more. Of course this helps me as it does from kindergarten to 6th grade. But I'd love to have more resources to use.

Here is that site
http://hukumusume.com/douwa/0_6/index.html

I'm not very interested in real people talking, or blogging, between nico nico, mixi, and ameba, I have enough of that. I just want to read stuff intended for children in japanese. If anyone has any links like that for me, it would be greatly appreciated.

I would not mind if it was textbook-esque, or children's book-esque, or children's magazine-esque... as long as its intended for children.

Comment: This question seems off-topic based on http://japanese.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask.  See also http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-good-sources-for-streaming-japanese-language-television and http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27/what-is-the-best-software-website-to-aid-learning-japanese

Comment: Maybe include this as a community wiki?

Comment: How very odd... my comment that I added most of these to the resources thread seems to have gotten lost somehow...

Answer (score 7):

Ha! Sawa posted his answer while I was writing this, but may as well post this anyway -- a few authors/works at Aozora Bunko possibly of interest.

- [Brothers Grimm](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/index_pages/person1091.html)
- [Kusuyama Masao](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/index_pages/person329.html)
- [Hans Christian Andersen](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/index_pages/person19.html)
- [Miyazawa Kenji](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/index_pages/person81.html) ([銀河鉄道の夜](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000081/card456.html), [注文の多い料理店](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000081/card43754.html))
- [Nankichi Niimi](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/index_pages/person121.html)
- [Takehisa Yumeji's 春](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000212/card46453.html)
- [Akutagawa Ryunosuke's 三つの宝](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000879/card1126.html)

Answer (score 6):

[青空文庫](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/) is among the most famous online public resources on literature in Japan. For some of them, the copyright has expired, in which case they are a little old. In other cases, the author agreed to provide it free. I think you would be particularly interested in the section:

児童書:9 文学:91 日本文学:913 小説、物語: http://yozora.kazumi386.org/9/1/ndck913.html

Answer (score 4):

Search keyword: [こども 新聞](http://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%81%93%E3%81%A9%E3%82%82+%E6%96%B0%E8%81%9E)

Some, if not most, major newspapers have editions targeted at children, and generous enough to make some of the articles freely available online. For example,

- [Asahi shimbun's](http://www.asagaku.com/) - no furigana
- [Yomiuri shimbun's](http://www.yomiuri.co.jp/kyoiku/children/weekly/) - with furigana
- [Mainichi shimbun's](http://mainichi.jp/life/edu/maishou/) - with furigana

---

Search keyword: [キッズ よみもの](http://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%82%AD%E3%83%83%E3%82%BA+%E3%82%88%E3%81%BF%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE)

You may be able to find some more websites created for children with these keywords. For example,

- [Product catalog tailored for children](http://kids.mediafactory.co.jp/index_bok.html)
- [CSR effort to create a learning space for children](http://pks.panasonic.co.jp/)

Answer (score 3):

I found another site thats great for reading materials.

http://etext.lib.virginia.edu/japanese/texts/titles-en.html